# how to set knex connection ssl options when using a connection string

Tags: postgresql, ssl, knex.js

How can I set my connection's ssl property to true when I'm using a connection string to initialize knex?  Similarly how to set the debug to true?  I would normally pass in a connection object but in this case I have to use a connection string from environment variables.

```js
    var database = {
        client: 'pg',
        connection: connstr //normally I would pass in the object below
        //connection: {
        //    "host": config.get('database_host'),
        //    "user": config.get('database_user'),
        //    "password": config.get('database_password'),
        //    "database": config.get('database_name'),
        //    "debug": config.get('database_debug'),
        //    "ssl":config.get('database_ssl')
        //}
    };
    
    var knex = require('knex')(database);
    knex.connection.ssl = true;  // this doesn't seem to do anything
```

Comment: connection: {
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl:true,
    }

Comment: My SSL Key has a passphrase, where should I enter the passphrase ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply add `?ssl=true` to the end of your connection string (at the end of the database name). For debug, either append `?debug=true` after setting ssl or `&debug=true` I'm actually not sure sorry so just try both.

Comment: `?ssl=true` was the solution for me.

Comment: Also `ssl : true` in the knexfile `connection` block works.

Comment: My SSL Key has a passphrase, where should I enter the passphrase ?

Comment: `?ssl=1` also works which is desirable in some cases (shorter/simpler to observe URLs)

Answer (score 8):

For pg >= 8.x, you'll need something like the following:

```
connection: {
  connectionString: dbConnection,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
}
```

This answer led me here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66898176/776167

You can read more [here](https://node-postgres.com/announcements#2020-02-25)

Comment: This is a good answer