# Connecting to Oracle with SSL

Tags: node.js, oracle, ssl, knex.js, node-oracledb

I am trying to connect to Oracle DB 12c from an electron (nodeJs) application.

I am creating the connection by passing parameters, using the knex library, like this:

```
knex({
            client: 'oracledb',
            connection: {
                host: hostItems + ':' + connection.Port,
                user: connection.UserName,
                password: connection.Password,
                database: connection.DatabaseName
            };
        });
```

In `knex` the connection parameter is the same as `node-oracledb` which is used internally.

It works for non-ssl connections like using port `1521`, but not for `2484` the standard oracle SSL port. I have the CA certs with me, but I dont know how to pass them.

For the SSL port I get `12547: TNS Lost Contact` which sounds about right as it cannot establish SSL connection.

I am trying to figure out `how to use SSL with node-oracledb`.

Comment: Listen to this conversation regarding Native Network Encryption vs SSL. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8NFpvXXbR_w&t=34m03s Do you really need SSL? For almost everyone, the answer is no...

Answer (score 0):

The official node-oracledb documentation contains a section describing [how to properly configure SSL/TLS](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-127-securely-encrypting-network-traffic-to-oracle-database).

Since the NodeJS application will be acting as the client in this communication scenario, it must provide the certificates during the handshake (as a browser would for an example).

Comment: My application is a third party one which is used to scan customers databases, I cannot change the servers. The documentation wasn't clear to me. What can I do client side to solve this?

Comment: Per the scenario description it seems the database server already supports SSL/TLS, thus there is no need to change anything there. The client is the one that should also support SSL/TLS. Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30652809/how-to-set-knex-connection-ssl-options-when-using-a-connection-string) will help.

Comment: You are correct, its the client which has the problem, I know the server has it enabled. That thread was for posgres, knex passes the connection object as-is to the underlying provider which in this case is `node-oracledb`, I cant seem to find an example for that.

Comment: The node-oracledb doc shows '[native network encryption](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#securenetwork)' but links to the [Oracle Database Security Guide](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=DBSEG) (see chapter 'Configuring Secure Sockets Layer Authentication') for steps on setting up SSL.  Network security is all handled in Oracle's networking stack and isn't specific to node-oracledb.